# Ehterpad configure script not finding the existing dir given via prefix option

Tags: 12.04, nodejs

I am following the official ubuntu guide to install etherpad [from here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Etherpad-liteInstallation).

When it asks to download and extract the latest version of etherpad, I do so. The version I downloaded is **node-v0.10.26.tar.gz**.

Since I am following the guide, the path of extracted directory is **/opt/etherpad/local/node-v0.10.26**

The guide then asks me to run configure script: " ./configure –-prefix=$HOME/local/node"

On doing so I get the following error:

```
gyp: –-prefix=/opt/etherpad/local/node not found (cwd: /opt/etherpad/local/node) while trying to load –-prefix=/opt/etherpad/local/node
Error running GYP
```

So I then rename the node-v0.10.26 directory to simply "node" and then run the command again and I again get the same error:

```
gyp: –-prefix=/opt/etherpad/local/node not found (cwd: /opt/etherpad/local/node) while trying to load –-prefix=/opt/etherpad/local/node
Error running GYP
```

If instead of $HOME I use /opt/etherpad, as in " ./configure –-prefix=/opt/etherpad/local/node" I still get the same error.

Any clues why is it giving the error?
OS is Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Try to type the two dashes in front of "prefix" manually.
It was a copy and paste error for me.